# Magento 2 datepicker locale as default date format

Tags: html, datepicker, magento2

```
 <input class="input-text" type="text" name="customerDob" style="width: 120px"
        data-validate="{required:true}"
        data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode() + '-dob'}, value: customerDob, datepicker: { storage: customerDob, options: {'dateFormat': 'dd/mm/yy'} }"/>
 <div class="mage-error" generated="true" style="display: none;" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode() + '-dob-error'}"></div>
```

In my `options: {'dateFormat': 'dd/mm/yy'}`
my date format is set to dd/mm/yy. I would like to change my date format regarding the locale date format e.g US: mm/dd/yy or Germany dd/mm/yy.

Answer (score 1):

```
'dateFormat': 'mm/dd/yy'
```

or

```
'dateFormat': 'mm/dd/yyyy'
```

is what you'll need to replace 'dateFormat': 'dd/mm/yy' with. Literally as easy as rearranging the letters.